# NavigationParameters - GetNavigationMode() is NULL while mocking NavigationParameters.

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, mocking, prism, static-methods

I tried mocking NavigationParameters and it is setting GetNavigationMode() as NULL. Is there any better way to mock an extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was bugging me for a while as well, and I finally found something that is at least a workaround. [This](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1483) issue shows that you can actually add internal parameters to the NavigationParameters, it just doesn't show up in intellisense. My test code ended up looking something like:

```
var navParams = new NavigationParameters();
navParams.AddInternalParameter("__NavigationMode", NavigationMode.Back);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Didn't work out for me. But your reference helped me to find a solution, that compiled (maybe it is a version issue, I use `Prism 7.1`:

```cs
var navParams = (INavigationParametersInternal)new NavigationParameters();
navParams.Add("__NavigationMode", NavigationMode.New);
```

Comment: How do you pass `navParams` as navigation parameter? casting it back to NavigationParameters?

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @thomas-kison, the `AddInternalParameter` api no longer seems to exist. A [search through the Prism repo](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/search?q=AddInternalParameter&unscoped_q=AddInternalParameter) only brings up the [issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1483) referenced by @batesiiic in their answer.

To add to @thomas-kison's answer by addressing @esteban-chornet's question, what I've found is that this solution will work by passing in the `INavigationParametersInternal` argument as `INavigationParameters`:

```cs
// arrange:
var navParams = (INavigationParametersInternal)new NavigationParameters();
navParams.Add("__NavigationMode", NavigationMode.Back);

// act:
_myCoolPageViewModel.OnNavigatedTo(navParams as INavigationParameters);

// assert whatever should happen in OnNavigatedTo given a NavigationMode of NavigationMode.Back
```

Hope this helps someone out!